# Suscribing to observable: RxJava + Retrofit + Repository pattern

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit, retrofit2, rx-java

I am trying to set up retrofit and rxjava for my app to make api calls to a webservice. I am having some trouble subscribing to my observable object in the main activity. The architecture follows the viewmodel/repository pattern, here is my code

Repository

```
class WisproRepository() {

    val request = ServiceBuilder.buildService(JsonPayments::class.java)
    val apicall: Observable<Payment> = request.getPostsV2(2, 100, "authorizationcode")

    fun getPayments(): Observable<Payment?>? {
        return apicall.subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
    }

}
```

ViewModel

```
class PaymentsViewModel : ViewModel() {

    var wisproRepository = WisproRepository()
    var payments_rx: Observable<Payment?>? = wisproRepository.getTopContributors()

}
```

MainActivity

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    var adapter: MyRecyclerViewAdapter? = null
    private var textView: TextView? = null

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        //Getting payment object and updating view
        val view_model: PaymentsViewModel by viewModels()
        view_model.payments_rx?.subscribe(....)

    }
```

Now, instead of observing the livedata I would have to subscribe to the Observable and setup recyclerview when the data arrives but I don't understand how to do that in the subscribe method. But I don't understand how to do that inside the subscribe method. Also, how can I access the data of the Payment inside the observable object ?

Also I do not understand these lines right here,

```
val request = ServiceBuilder.buildService(JsonPayments::class.java)
val apicall: Observable<Payment> = request.getPostsV2(2,100, "authorization code")
apicall.subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread()).observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
```

Are `subscribeOn` and `observeOn` performing the call? And if they are, how does it work (I am used to enqueue method)? Am I missing something? How can I setup `onResponse` and `onFailure` callbacks?

Comment: Is your api call or not? What is your problem?

Comment: @CôngHải eddited the post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use `retrofit2:adapter-rxjava2` it automatically wrap your API call to `Cold Observable` and auto-execute `API Request` when you subscribe.

> Are `subscribeOn` and `observeOn` performing the call

It doesn't perform call API, API call when you call `subscribe` it makes your API request run in `Background Thread` and handles response in `Main Thread`

> How can I setup `onResponse` and onFailure callbacks?

In `subscribe` method you can pass `Consumer` to handle `Response` or `Error`

```
view_model.payments_rx?.subscribe({
 // response
}, {
 // error
})
```

Answer (score 1):

An observable is basically a stream of events, each event is of the type that you're observing. In this case `Payment`. Every time you get a `Payment` object, the `onNext()` method of your observable is called. Once the stream is done emitting events `onComplete` will be called, and in case of an error, `onError` (both of these are **terminal** events)

You haven't posted the `JsonPayments` class so I can't say for sure, but you need to be creating an observable in `getPostsV2()` and returning it so you can observe it or subscribe to it.

If you want `onResponse` and `onFailure` callbacks, you could essentially wrap your `Payment` object to `Result<Payment>` where `Result` has both of those properties. Your final observable will be `Observable<Result<Payment>>` where each event will be of type `Result<Payment>`.

Comment: in my interface the return type of getPostsV2() is an observable, my question is how to perform some actions on the suscribe method. Thanks for the Result<Payment> insight btw.